# SQL display rows with grouping rows with same one column value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to grouping rows with same wolumn customer name  and also display other rows .I have this table

```
id   ||    name_customer ||   date    
1          name 1             21/07/2018    
2          name 2             22/07/2018   
3          name 3             23/07/2018     
5          name 1             27/07/2018
```

So The resulst that I want is : 
to order rows by date desc first and grouping by same name customer :

```
id   ||    name_customer ||   date
5          name 1             27/07/2018
1          name 1             21/07/2018
3          name 3             23/07/2018 
2          name 2             22/07/2018
```

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
GROUP BY name_customer
order BY date DESC
```

but it didn't work

Any one can help me please.

Comment: Why does row with ID 1 appear twice in your result set?

Comment: Sorry I mean row with ID 2

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Please don't ever say "but it didn't work" without telling us *what* didn't work. Did you get an error, too many rows, too few, wrong values, ...? `GROUP BY name_customer` means: "give me one result row per customer name". There are three different customer names, but you want four result rows, so it's obvious this can't work. Please also tag your MySQL version, because answers can vary for different versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to sort  the customers by their maximum date first and then sort within customer by date again.

As of MySQL 8.0:

```
select *
from my_table
order by
  max(date) over (partition by name_customer) desc,
  name_customer,
  date desc;
```

In older versions:

```
select *
from my_table
order by
  (
    select max(date)
    from my_table m
    where m.name_customer = my_table.name_customer
  ) desc,
  name_customer,
  date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use customer name in `order by`

```
    SELECT * FROM my_table     
  order BY name_customer,date desc
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzh4cEoYXVKfvs6ZmSVhfG/2

```
id  name_customer   date
5   name 1  2018-07-27
1   name 1  2018-07-21
2   name 2  2018-07-22
3   name 3  2018-07-23
```

Comment: Neither of these will give the required results.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin +1 because your first answer is correct. However, I'd consider removing the rest. I'm not convinced the OP knows what GROUP BY does, and I suspect they were trying to use it to order the result.

Comment: I agree with Barry that you should remove the rest. `GROUP BY id, ...` does exactly nothing, as the ID is unique. I disagree, though, that the first part is correct, because the OP wants ID 3 before ID 2, probably because of the later date.